# ValueError when inserting data into numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to insert data from a dataframe `df` into a numpy array `matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues`. However, I basically need to add the value associated with a row of `df['Coupon']` into each column of a corresponding row of the array for as many columns as the number `numberofcoupon_payments = row1['months_to_maturity']/6`. I get the error `ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,2) into shape (1,61)` in the line `np.insert(matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues, row_no+1, rowtobeadded, 0)` and I understand why, but I don't know how to proceed.

The code I am using is as follows:

```
matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues = np.zeros((number_of_rows_and_columns, number_of_rows_and_columns))
        rowtobeadded = np.zeros(number_of_rows_and_columns)
        for (i1,row1) in df.iterrows():
            numberofcoupon_payments = row1['months_to_maturity']/6
            for row_no in range(int(number_of_rows_and_columns)):
                for index_no in range(int(numberofcoupon_payments)):
                    coupon = row1['coupon']
                    rowtobeadded = np.full((1, numberofcoupon_payments), coupon)
                    np.insert(matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues, row_no+1, rowtobeadded, 0)
```

**Edit**:
The dataframe `df` looks like this:

```
   months_to_maturity          on_the_run_dt          asset_id  \
0                    5  2015-07-02 00:00:00.0  00102CC07F4B02CA   
1                    6  2015-06-25 00:00:00.0  00102CD0FB2A023F   
2                   11  2015-04-02 00:00:00.0  00102CFED3C500D4   
3                   12  2015-06-25 00:00:00.0  00102C37122B0230   
4                   23  2015-03-02 00:00:00.0  00102C76082B0069

              orig_iss_dt            maturity_dt  pay_freq_cd  coupon  \
0   2015-07-02 00:00:00.0  2015-12-31 00:00:00.0          NaN   0.000   
1   2015-06-25 00:00:00.0  2015-12-24 00:00:00.0          NaN   0.000   
2   2015-04-02 00:00:00.0  2016-03-31 00:00:00.0          NaN   0.000   
3   2015-06-25 00:00:00.0  2016-06-23 00:00:00.0          NaN   0.000   
4   2015-03-02 00:00:00.0  2017-02-28 00:00:00.0            2   0.500


       closing_price cpn_type_cd  months_to_maturity_1  FACE_VALUE  
0       99.944389        FXDI                     5  24000101.6  
1       99.960889        FXDI                     6  24000366.4  
2       99.866806        FXDI                    11  25000267.5
```

Desired output Array:
For example I need the array to look like this, if the `months_to_maturity` column of `df` has values `6`,`12`,`18`:

```
array([[coupon     0     0      0], 
       [coupon   coupon  0      0], 
       [coupon   coupon coupon  0]])
```

Thank You

Comment: This may not be that hard to do but it would be much easier to understand your question if you provided a small dataframe and desired output array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'months_to_maturity':[5,6,11,12,23],'coupon' : [0,0,0,0,.5]})
matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues = np.zeros((5,5))

for i,row in df.iterrows():
    matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues[i,0:row.months_to_maturity/6] = row['coupon']

    matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues
array([[ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [ 0.5,  0.5,  0.5,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

Comment: Thanks. But unfortunately the `matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues` prints out to be `[[ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 ..., 
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0. ...,  0.  0.  0.]]`

Comment: The `row['coupon']` values don't see to be getting added.

Comment: i don't know what to tell you, it works on my simple example, can you work build up your data from here?

Comment: Yeah, the logic makes sense. And sorry, what do you mean by "can you work build up your data from here?"

Comment: i don't know, i tried with your data and it still works, are you sure you're whole matrix is zero? and not just the rows that you can see? try this: `matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues[matrix_of_coupons_and_facevalues[:,0] != 0]`